# How to make a component that support both FMX and VCL

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, vcl

The question has already been asked, but I still can't find a good way to do it.

I made a component who simply draws some stuff on a `TForm`. Basically, it's exactly the same code regarding FMX or VCL, but on FMX it's using `FMX.Forms` and on VCL it's using `Vcl.Forms`.

1. How to make my component compatible with both framework? Ideally, I don't want to split the unit (one `FMX.myunit.pas` and one `VCL.myUnit.pas`, for example).
2. How can I make my component appear on the Tools Palette only for a `VCL project` **or** only for an `FMX project` **or** for `both projects`?
3. How, in my `.dpr`/`.dproj`, can I say that my project uses the VCL or FMX framework? Can a project use both frameworks, VCL and FMX?
4. For FMX components, why do I need to call `RegisterComponents('myGroup', [TMyControl]);` followed by `RegisterFmxClasses([TMyControl]);` (It looks like this in all samples I have seen).

Comment: Not an answer to you base question but... A component don't draw on a form, at least directly. A component draw in his own window which is a child window of a TForm or other container.

Comment: Use conditional compilation and include file. As an example, look in [ICS source code](https://svn.overbyte.be/svn/ics/trunk/Source/) to see how it has been done.

Comment: @fpiette: A component (`TComponent`) need not be visual at all. There are visual components (like `TButton` or `TLabel`) and non-visual components (like `TTimer`). A visual component is called a control (`TControl`). And controls are of two types: windowed controls (like `TButton`) and graphic controls (like `TLabel`). A windowed control has a true window (HWND) to draw within, while a graphic control draws in a parent control's window.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand exactly, and on FMX their is windowed control (in most case) so no HWND, a visual component just draw himself on a given canvas (the canvas of the form).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Do you really think that I don't know that?

Comment: @fpiette: I think you already knew that, but your first comment was not very precise, so for the benefit of other people reading this Q, I added some details.

Comment: "draw some stuff on a TForm. basically it's exactly the same code..". Perhaps you can post that code here so someone might work out a solution for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just made a component who simply draw some stuff on a TForm.

A UI control should not be drawing on the Form at all.  It should be drawing on the `Canvas` that the VCL/FMX framework provides to it, such as in an overridden `Paint()` method.

> How to make my component compatible with both framework? Ideally I don't want to split the unit (one FMX.myunit.pas and one VCL.myUnit.pas for exemple)

You don't need to use Unit Scopes in your own units, unless you are sharing units across packages and want to differentiate between them.

If you don't make separate units for each framework, then you will need to `IFDEF` the unit as needed when using framework-specific coding.

If you write purely framework-agnostic code, then a single package can be used for both frameworks.  But if you need to write framework-specific code (ie, because of UI code, etc), then you will need to make separate packages for each framework.

As for the component itself, if you go the IFDEF route then try to derive your component from a base class that exists in both frameworks, if possible.

For non-visual components, derive from `TComponent`, it behaves the exact same in both frameworks.

For visual controls, derive from `TControl` or descendant as needed.  Just note that there are differences in how each framework implements visual controls, so you will likely need to `IFDEF` your implementation code accordingly, or use separate units for each framework.

> How to make my component appear in the tools palette only for VCL project or only for FMX project or for both projects ?

A package can have an affinity for a specific framework (see further below).

If it specifies a particular framework, then that is the only framework it will appear for.  If it does not specify a framework, then it will be available for both frameworks.

When you register a UI control, you should call [`GroupDescendentsWith()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.GroupDescendentsWith) to group your control to `TControl`'s class group, eg:

```pascal
RegisterComponents('My Control', [TMyControl]);
GroupDescendentsWith(TMyControl, TControl);
```

Don't fully qualify the Unit Scope for `TControl`, either in this call, or in your `uses` clause. Use just the `Controls` unit and let the compiler pick between `FMX.Controls.TControl` or `Vcl.Controls.TControl` depending on which version of `TControl` is available based on which framework your package is being compiled for.

> How in my dpr/dproj can I say that my project use VCL or FMX framework?

In the `.dproj`, in the first `<PropertyGroup>`, there is a `<FrameworkType>` element available (add it if it is missing), which can be set to either `VCL`, `FMX`, or `None`.

> Can a project use both Framework, VCL and FMX?

Not *officially*, no.  But, there are *unofficial* ways (ie, 3rd party solutions) to do it.  I would not recommend doing this inside a package, only inside an application.

> For fmx components, why I need to do `RegisterComponents('myGroup', [TMyControl]);` followed by `RegisterFmxClasses([TMyControl]);` (It's look like this in all sample I saw).

All that is really doing is grouping `TMyControl` to the `TFmxObject` class group, which is only available when the FMX framework is active.  It is just another group used for filtering the display of components within the IDE.  Grouping a UI control to the `TControl` class group accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: But if component is in the same file (unit) it is not possible to install it in the IDE even if you use IFDEF to separate code. Same unit cannot be included in the 2 different packages.

Comment: @Livius A unit can be used in separate packages. You just can't have those packages loaded in memory at the same time. You can have those packages installed in the IDE at the same time as long as they are enabled only on a per-project basis and you don't work on those projects at the same time. Otherwise, the unit should be in a 3rd package that the other packages can then require. But then the unit shouldn't be IFDEF'ed anymore and should contain only framework/platform-agnostic code

Comment: The IDE refuse install of such package (if i remember correctly). If you have a way i am really interested, as i need the way for VirtualStringTree which i have ported to FMX github.com/livius2/Virtual-TreeView

Comment: @Livius sounds like the basis for a new question